# I am getting an error while trying to run autogen using a local LLM

Tags: large-language-model, autogen

Below is the Code I am running. Note that I am using LM Studio (LLM: Llama 2) and I have double checked to make sure that the server number is correct.

```
from autogen import AssistantAgent, UserProxyAgent

config_list = [
    {
        "api_type": "open_ai",
        "api_base": "http://localhost:1234/v1",
        "api_key": "NULL"
    }
]

llm_config = {'config_list': config_list}

assistant = AssistantAgent(
    name="assistant",
    llm_config = llm_config
)

user_proxy = UserProxyAgent(
    name="user_proxy",
    human_input_mode="NEVER",
    max_consecutive_auto_reply=100,
)

task = """write a python method to output numbers 1 to 100"""

user_proxy.initiate_chat(
    assistant,
    message=task
)
```

This is the exact result I get after running python app.py (name of the program):

user_proxy (to assistant):

write a python method to output numbers 1 to 100

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "app.py", line 26, in <module>
    user_proxy.initiate_chat(
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\agentchat\conversable_agent.py", line 550, in initiate_chat
    self.send(self.generate_init_message(**context), recipient, silent=silent)
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\agentchat\conversable_agent.py", line 348, in send  
    recipient.receive(message, self, request_reply, silent)
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\agentchat\conversable_agent.py", line 481, in receive
    reply = self.generate_reply(messages=self.chat_messages[sender], sender=sender)
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\agentchat\conversable_agent.py", line 906, in generate_reply
    final, reply = reply_func(self, messages=messages, sender=sender, config=reply_func_tuple["config"])
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\agentchat\conversable_agent.py", line 625, in generate_oai_reply
    response = client.create(
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\oai\client.py", line 247, in create
    response = self._completions_create(client, params)
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\autogen\oai\client.py", line 327, in _completions_create    
    response = completions.create(**params)
  File "C:\Users\Rohun\Development\AutoGen\env\lib\site-packages\openai\_utils\_utils.py", line 299, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
TypeError: create() got an unexpected keyword argument 'api_type'
```

I am unsure what the error above is referring as I looked on the autogen github link and it shows them using 'api_type' multiple times in the config list. How to resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the api_type was removed recently from autogen to retain compatibility with the openai api.
[see autogen roadmap](https://github.com/orgs/microsoft/projects/989/views/3?pane=issue&itemId=41243873)

Comment: Please help the questioner by providing information on how to replace the api_type argument that has now been removed. Is it simply not needed?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following 3 changes in your code:

1. ```
     #"api_type": "open_ai", #comment out api_type
   ```
2. ```
     "base_url": "http://localhost:1234/v1", #replace api_type with base_url
   ```
3. ```
     "api_key": "sk-111111111111111"  #just a placeholder
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the error suggests a mismatch in expected configuration parameters within the AutoGen setup. The correct configuration parameter for specifying the API base URL is not `api_base` but `base_url`.

```
    {
        "api_type": "open_ai",
        "base_url": "http://localhost:1234/v1",
        ...
    }
]
```

Check the migration guide: https://microsoft.github.io/autogen/docs/Migration-Guide/

For a more detailed explanation and guidance, including how to correctly set up and configure your environment, refer to the video at this link: https://youtu.be/aWml0ncqPnU?t=400